# Craft 3 - login problem on mobile

Tags: craft3, users

I have a site which is online now.

This site has a set password, log in, etc. features for my users. My users are able to sign in or set password (all user operations) on any browser but when they try to set the password or login (all user operations) on mobile, the process is never ended and finally crashed.

Comment: Can you please check the logs ?

Comment: @inrsaurabh i see "Request didn’t meet the user agent and IP requirement for maintaining a user session." in the logs.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Craft requires that a browser has a user agent string and IP address for a valid authenticated session, and once that session starts, the user agent string must remain the same for the remainder of the session.

It sounds like whatever browsers are being used on the mobile devices aren't providing this.

You can alter this behavior with these config settings:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#requireuseragentandipforsession

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#requirematchinguseragentforsession